# What patterns exist to coordinate important data related calls (API + Database) in a class?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm looking for the best way to structure a class (or set of classes) that **coordinate an ordered set of  API calls or steps** and then persist mixed data from the results of those API calls and steps.  Ideally there would be rollback handling for failure scenarios to cleanup any created API data, in the case where persisted data fails or doesn't pass certain validations.  I have created a similar structure with some Ruby pseudo code below, however this just doesn't feel right.

Any help with a better way to structure this would be greatly appreciated!

```
class SomeImportantAction

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def run!
    result = API.get(...)
    result_2 = OtherAPI.post(...)
    some_var = do_some_work()
    update_obj(result, some_var)
    create_something_new(result,result_2)
  end

  private

  def update_obj(result,somevar)
    ...
  end

  def create_something_new(arg,arg)
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is to have one method working on one level of abstraction.
Your aim is to gather information (with API calls) and to save it to DB. This is top level:

```
def run!
  result = make_api_calls(@obj)
  another_result = do_some_work()

  if results_valid?(result, another_result)
    save_results(result, another_result)
  else
    cleanup(result, another_result)
  end
end

def make_api_calls(@obj)
  result = API.get(...)
  result_2 = OtherAPI.post(...)
  combine_results(result, result_2)
rescue
  handle_api_fail()
end
```

Reading `run!` method you can clearly say what the task is doing. And then, if interested, you can inspect each method.
Each method that called in `run!` should then operate on lower level of abstraction - make API calls, save to DB. But again, only one level - don't dig into establishing DB connection or something like that.

Once you split work into smaller and task-specific methods, you can see groups of methods that only use each other (like API calls and handling related exceptions). That would be candidates for a new class.

For example, you need series of API calls to create a user profile - fetch auth info, fetch profile picture, call some API to add user's role, book something etc. That is a bunch of API calls that work as a transaction - all succeed or have no effect if one fails. This should be organized as a class - it is simpler to use (less API calls to keep in mind), to debug and to test.

Don't be afraid to create classes and methods. Even one-lined methods can help significantly.